# Using Python + OpenStreetMap's to Get Highways Within Bounding Box

Tags: python, api, openstreetmap

I'm looking to use OpenStreetMap to get the roads (highways, etc.) within a bounding box from a python script and am struggling to get started.

I started attempting this in Java using the example they provided, with my code looking like:

```
...
String string = OPENSTREETMAP_API_06 + "map?bbox=" + left + "," + bottom + "," + right + "," + top;
    System.out.println("STRING: "+string);
    URL osm = new URL(string);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) osm.openConnection();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
    return docBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
...
```

This returns all the nodes within that bounding box, but none of them have the tags such as highway that I'm looking for.I'm now looking to do this in Python as that's what the rest of this project is in and Java was just an attempt to use an easier API.

I know this isn't much to go on, but I was hoping somebody here could point me to an example or something that helps me understand how to get the road segments (ways) that exist in a particular bounding box. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at *ways*. Although *nodes* are essential for ways they don't have the [highway tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) you are looking for. Instead these tags are attached to ways.

To get more familiar with the OSM data model start reading in the OSM wiki about [elements](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). It also helps a lot to start one of the [top three OSM editors](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editors#Top_three_editors), load the area you are interested in and look at the data.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Accepted.